# How to highlight active thumbnail?

Tags: jquery, css, thumbnails

I was wondering how I could highlight the active thumbnail on this page http://www.doublezerofilms.com/doublezero-template-webSamples.html so when it's clicked it stays on the mouseover img until another thumbnail is clicked?

this is the code I'm using to select the video and below that the html thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Thumb1").click(function () {
        $("#hidden").hide().html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38366163?autoplay=1"  width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>').fadeIn(4e3);
        $("#leftsidePlayer").text("This is some text on the consulting video!")
    });

<div class="thumbsWrap">
                        <div>
                            <div id="Thumb1" class="fadehover">
                            <img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
                            <img src="images/thumb1-over.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
                            </div>

                            <div id="Thumb2" class="fadehover">
                            <img src="images/thumb2.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
                            <img src="images/thumb2-over.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
                            </div>

                            <div id="Thumb3" class="fadehover">
                            <img src="images/thumb3.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
                            <img src="images/thumb3-over.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
                            </div>

                            <div id="Thumb4" class="fadehover" style="margin:0px">
                            <img src="images/thumb4.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
                            <img src="images/thumb4-over.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

hover code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img.a").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, "fast")
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, "fast")
    })
});
```

Comment: Increase your acceptance rating by marking valid answers.  Also, include your hover script.

Answer (score 0):

You never posted your code that deals with fading them in and out, but this is basically what you would do.

```
//when a div is clicked add an active class to it
$('.thumbsWrap').on('click', '.fadehover', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

//in hover event check if parent has the 'active class'. If so then don't fade it out.
$("img.a").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: "0"
    }, "fast")
}, function () {
    if ( !$(this).parent().hasClass('active') ) {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           opacity: "1"
       }, "fast")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thx for the responses guys, not in  the office till later. I will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

As i see you are changing opacity to highlight thumbnails(in your hover). So here something like you want : http://jsfiddle.net/fnfJH/
When you click a div, it changes div's opacity that already 1 to 0.5, and changes new clicked to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to create a CSS to hide you image have class a for example:

```
img.transparent {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Now Add click event on button

```
$("img.a").click(function () {
 $(this).addClass('transparent');
});
```

Now edit your mouse over it should not effect on active image

```
$("img.a").hover(function () {
if(!($(this).hasClass('transparent'))) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, "fast");
}
    }, function () {
if(!($(this).hasClass('transparent'))) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, "fast")
}
    })
```

Comment: I forgot you also need to inative other class on click of other button. You can do it to remove class first on click event from all images in your tabs and then add class as it in above example